# How to error handle partition rebalancing?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, message-queue, apache-pulsar

In the deployment environment, [Apache Pulsar](https://pulsar.apache.org/) is used as MsgQ broker.

**Goal** is to select the Go client library that allow consumer to error handle amidst consumer group rebalancing.

Consumer group rebalancing can be triggered by a number of factors as the participants of the group change, which leads to the reassignment of partitions across the consumers. During a rebalance **message processing is paused**, impacting throughput.

I learnt that [segmentio-kafka-client-library](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go) has introduced [fix](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go/issues/274#issuecomment-520048752) to error handle consumer group rebalancing.

Sample code from [a testcase](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go/blob/294fbdbf43ce5c2bc6aa89d8a35db949e1f95367/example_consumergroup_test.go#L45C2-L45C2)

```
msg, err := reader.ReadMessage(ctx)
                    if err != nil {
                        if errors.Is(err, kafka.ErrGenerationEnded) {
                            // generation has ended.  commit offsets.  in a real app,
                            // offsets would be committed periodically.
                            gen.CommitOffsets(map[string]map[int]int64{"my-topic": {partition: offset + 1}})
                            return
                        }

                        fmt.Printf("error reading message: %+v\n", err)
                        return
                    }
```

---

So, plan is to use kafka-go from segmentio, but,

1. Does [segmentio-kafka-go-client](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go) support talking to Apache pulsar broker?
2. if no, Does [apache-plusar-client-go-lib](https://github.com/apache/pulsar-client-go) support a consumer to error handle rebalancing? I see this [issue](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/issues/12224) unresolved